# AWS Lambda NodeJS 12

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, asynchronous, aws-lambda, async-await

My code sometimes returns the expected values from the return blocks, sometimes returns part of the response, sometimes returns null... I'm assuming I'm not being sync but idk where

```
require('dotenv').config()

const { Client } = require('pg')
const client = new Client({
    user: process.env.PG_USER,
    host: process.env.PG_HOST,
    database: process.env.PG_DATABASE,
    password: process.env.PG_PASSWORD,
    port: process.env.PG_PORT,
})


exports.handler = async function (event, context) {
    console.log("hi")
        try {
            console.log("try")
            await client.connect()
            const res = await client.query("insert into accounts (email , phone , first , last , password , role ) values ('" + event.email + "', '" + event.phone + "', '" + event.first + "','" + event.last + "', '" + event.password + "', '" + event.role + "')")
            await client.end();
            return {
                "body": "Success",
                "statusCode": 201
            }
        } catch (e) {
            console.log("fail")
            await client.end();
            return {
                "body": "not null",
                "statusCode": 200
            }

        }
}
```

Comment: can you print console?

Comment: Yes, it hits all the console logs, hi try and fail

Comment: Print out you error with `console.log(e)`;

Comment: INFO Error: Client has already been connected. You cannot reuse a client.

weird because i'm calling client.end()